# Children's book about a girl who lived behind a wall

Tags: identification-request

I'm looking for a children's book my girlfriend read when she was a kid. The book is about a girl who lived behind a tall wall. She could see behind the wall using her swing. There was a forest on the other side of the wall which she and her dog went to without their parents knowing. She befriended a wolf or a fox there, and throughout the story, some stuff happens that her parents find out, the dog is probably killed by the fox or the wolf. What book was this?
some additional info:

- she read the story around 9 years ago
- the book had a red-orange cover
- it was illustrated but she can't remember any of the illustrations
- the story was for the age range of 10-15
- it was a series of novels

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please look though the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) to see if you/your girlfriend can answer any of the prompts there. If so, please [edit] further details into your question. For example, around when was this? (We have no idea how old your girlfriend is). Did it have illustrations? If so, in what style? What kind of dog was it? Where was the book from? In what language was it written? Why did she go out beyond the wall? And so forth.